# Remove Duplicates and Original from C# List

Tags: c#, list, duplicates

I have a List of custom types where I want to remove the duplicate and the original if a duplicate is found. Can only be one possible duplicate.

I can overide Equals and GetHashCode and then use Distinct but this only removes the duplicate. I need to remove both original and duplicate... Any ideas for something elegant so I don't have to use a hammer.

Comment: post the relevant code.

Comment: can you provide a coded example of what it is you are working with this will actually help others to gain an understanding of what you are trying to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy`, followed by `Where (g => g.Count() == 1)` to filter out all records that have duplicates:

```
var res = orig.GroupBy(x => x).Where(g => g.Count() == 1).Select(g => g.Key);
```

In order for this to work, you still need to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var itemsExistingExactlyOnce = list.GroupBy(x => x)
    .Where(group => group.Count() == 1)
    .Select(group => group.Key);
```